# How to stop and pause a video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to make a video player using scilab gui. I am using scilab gui in the front end and ffmpeg in the back end. I am able to start the video but I cannot stop or pause it. Any idea regarding how to stop and pause the video will be appreciated thoroughly?

Comment: How do you start the video?

Comment: I use the command -   unix_g("ffplay -i video.avi") to start the video.But it opens up the video in a completely new window.

Comment: If some how I am able to put this video on my predifinrd axes of GUI , I think , I will be able to stop it by simply deleting all the children of the object axes using the command-
"delete(object.axes.children)"
If anyone have  any idea, please help.I really need this as early as possible